# php array sort within array based on the value

Tags: php

I have array like below

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1280
            [id] => 1280
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2261
            [id] => 2261
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1280
            [id] => 1280
        )
)
```

In php, How do I sort from low to high based on the value of "id" ?

Comment: I believe this should serve your purpose,http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php

Answer (score 13, accepted):

use [usort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php), like:

```
function sortById($x, $y) {
    return $x['id'] - $y['id'];
}

usort($array, 'sortById');
echo "<pre>"; print_r($array);
```

Comment: You are rocking man, thanks for quick

Comment: Note that while this is generally true, it is not for float values below 1. You should take the sign of the difference before returning the comparison.

Answer (score 0):

use **array_multisort()** like below:

```
<?php
$multiArray = Array(
    Array("id" => 120, "name" => "Defg"),
    Array("id" => 62, "name" => "Abcd"),
    Array("id" => 99, "name" => "Bcde"),
    Array("id" => 2, "name" => "Cdef"));
$tmp = Array();
foreach($multiArray as &$ma)
    $tmp[] = &$ma["id"];
array_multisort($tmp, $multiArray);
foreach($multiArray as &$ma)
    echo $ma["id"]."<br/>";

/* Outputs
    2
62
99
120
*/
?>
```