# WP_Query - order attachments by filename?

Tags: wordpress, arguments, attachment

Is there any way to order attachments by **filename** within a WP_Query?

For example, in the arguments:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment', 
    'post_status' => 'inherit',
    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'orderby' => 'filename'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are no orderby filename option in get attachments argument. You need to sort by yourself attachments array based on available value from attachement array. To sort by filename you may use guid value.

Please read this link to sort array by value 
[php array sort within array based on the value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19534608/php-array-sort-within-array-based-on-the-value)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

[basename](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) gives you each attachment filename and you can sort by that using [usort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php). If you change the comparison operator (> to <) or switch return values (-1 : 1 to 1 : -1) the result will be reverse.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment', 
    'post_status' => 'inherit',
    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
);

if ( empty( $images = get_posts( $args ) ) ) {
    return;
}

usort( $images, function( $img1,  $img2 ) {
    return ( basename( $img1->guid ) > basename( $img2->guid ) ) ? -1 : 1;
} );
```

Comment: This answer is missing its explanation and I expected to see a spaceship operator here.